# CSS/JS: fixed header with variable size - dynamic body top-margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a small website project which i like to do purely with html/css and js without any external scripts and such.

My problem:
I got a header which is always fixed (**position: fixed**) on the screen. While scrolling down the body disappears behind the fixed header and **might cause the header to increase in height** (by appending other divs to the header).

This can also happen on mobile display when items get stacked in another order. (for this im using css grid)

**Now, of course i want to avoid the body getting overlapped by the header.**

If the header had a constant width i could just apply some top-margin to the body and I'm done. But since this is not the case I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution...

My first thought is using setInterval() and constantly checking the size of the  header and ajusting the margin of the body like that... But this doesn't seem right. **Can I somehow directly link the margin of the body to the height of the header?**

Comment: Probably you could use the concept of a 'sticky footer' and replicate it for your header? https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Make a single function for editing elements of the header.

```
function editHeader("<add>/<remove>", "<data>"/<element_obj>){
    /*Add or remove header elements*/

    //===========================================================
    /* Style your body margin by calculating the current header height*/
    //===========================================================

}
```

Call the above function for any element update operation on the header. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you share the code with the post. BTW you can use `vh`css unit instead llikr:

```
.header{
   position: fixed;
   margin-top: 5vh;
}
```

Using `vh` you're setting the margin of relative to the body height. This might help. but if you're header has too much content consider using a breadcrumb to collapse them in on small screen.